# How to display the value of function in tkinter?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, tkinter, stopwatch

I am new to python and tkinter and I have decided that I will make a stopwatch.
I have gooled alot and find many useful information, but I still haven't found how to display value of a function in tkinter. Here is my current code:

```
import time
from tkinter import*
import os

root = Tk()

def clock(event):
    second = 0
    minute = 0
    hour = 0  
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.99)
        second +=1
        print(hour,":",minute,":",second)
    return

def stop(event):
    time.sleep(1500)

def clear(event):
    os.system('cls')


button1 = Button(root, text="Start")
button2 = Button(root, text="Stop")
button3 = Button(root, text="Clear")

button1.bind("<Button-1>", clock)
button2.bind("<Button-1>", stop)
button3.bind("<Button-1>", clear)

button1.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
button2.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=2)
button3.grid(row=2, column=4, columnspan=2)


root.mainloop()
```

I am aware that the code isn't perefect yet(especially the functions stop and clear).

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using callback functions (i.e. call to your function when something happens — when clicking a button for example):

Quoting portions of [Tkinter Callbacks](https://web.archive.org/web/20200302040546id_/http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm):

> In Tkinter, a callback is Python code that is called by Tk when
> something happens. For example, the **Button** widget provides a **command**
> callback which is called when the user clicks the button. You also use
> callbacks with event bindings.
>
> You can use any callable Python object as a *callback*. This includes
> ordinary *functions, bound methods, lambda expressions*, and *callable
> objects*. This document discusses each of these alternatives briefly.
>
> ...
>
> To use a function object as a callback, pass it directly to Tkinter.
>
> ```
> from Tkinter import *
>
> def callback():
>     print "clicked!"
>
> b = Button(text="click me", command=callback)
> b.pack()
>
> mainloop()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your sample code which function's value you want to display.

Regardless, a good way to do accomplish something like that in `tkinter` is by creating instances of its `StringVar` [Variable](https://web.archive.org/web/20201031100214id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)  class and then specifying them as the `textvariable` option of another widget. After this is done, any changes to the value of the `StringVar` instance will automatically update the associated widget's text.

The code below illustrates this:

```
import os
import time
import tkinter as tk

class TimerApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master=None)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.elapsed = 0
        self.refresh_timer()
        self.after_id = None  # used to determine and control if timer is running

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.timer = tk.StringVar()
        self.timer.set('')
        self.timer_label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.timer)
        self.timer_label.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start_clock)
        self.button1.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Stop", command=self.stop_clock)
        self.button2.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=2)
        self.button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Clear", command=self.clear_clock)
        self.button3.grid(row=2, column=4, columnspan=2)

    def start_clock(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.after_id = self.after(1000, self.update_clock)

    def stop_clock(self):
        if self.after_id:
            self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
            self.after_id = None

    def clear_clock(self):
        was_running = True if self.after_id else False
        self.stop_clock()
        self.elapsed = 0
        self.refresh_timer()
        if was_running:
            self.start_clock()

    def update_clock(self):
        if self.after_id:
            now = time.time()
            delta_time = round(now - self.start_time)
            self.start_time = now
            self.elapsed += delta_time
            self.refresh_timer()
            self.after_id = self.after(1000, self.update_clock)  # keep updating

    def refresh_timer(self):
        hours, remainder = divmod(self.elapsed, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
        self.timer.set('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds))

app = TimerApp()
app.master.title('Timer')
app.mainloop()
```